# How to get all the substrings matching given word along with their count in mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following problem retrieving data from MongoDB using spring boot.

Here is my Schema:

```
class Item
{
    @Id
    String _id;
    String description;
}
```

Let's say the database has following content:

```
{"Id1", "carrot vegetable"},
{"Id2", "vegies is a brand"},
{"Id3", "I am Vegetarian"},
{"Id4", "Potato vegetable"},
{"Id5", "Fruits"}
```

what I'm trying to achieve is get terms which start with "veg" and the count of them.
That is Something like this:

```
{"vegetable", 2},
{"vegies", 1},
{"vegetarian", 1}
```

So far, I have came across **IndexOfCP** operation which can find substring from string.

```
db.Item.aggregate([ { $match:{ description:/veg/gi } }, { $project:{ index:{ $indexOfCP:[ { $toLower:"$description" }, "veg" ] }, description:1 } }, { $sort:{ index:1 } } ])
```

But I could not find the matching term and its count in the resultset.

How I can do this in mongo command and in spring boot.

Comment: what should be the output in case of {"Id6", "vegetable is vegetable or vegetable"}

Comment: @shubham it should count as 1. O/P would be: {"vegetable" : 1 } not {"vegetable" : 3}

Comment: And in this case ==> {"Id7", "vegetable vegies   Vegetarian"} ?

Comment: @shubham In that case: {"vegetable" : 1}, {"vegies" : 1}, {"vegetarian" : 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Item.aggregate([ 
   { $match:{ description:/veg/gi } },
   { 
     $project :{
        matchedAndUniqWords:{
             $reduce:{
               input:{ $filter:{input:{$split:[{"$toLower":"$description"}," "]},as:"w",cond:{$ne:[{$indexOfCP:["$$w","veg"]},-1]}}},
               initialValue:[],
               in:{
                   $cond:[{$in:["$$this","$$value"]},{$concatArrays:[[],"$$value"]},{$concatArrays:[["$$this"],"$$value"]}]
                  }     
           }
        }
       }
     },
     {
      $unwind:{path : "$matchedAndUniqWords"}
   },
   {
     $group:{_id:"$matchedAndUniqWords",count:{"$sum":1}}
   }]);
```

Comment: will you please explain this query.

Comment: this query splits description and then filter only matched words with your query then it reduces this resultant array to produce unique and matched word as you said that output of this should be {"Id6", "vegetable is vegetable or vegetable"} be as {"vegetable" : 1 } then in unwind stage it unwinds matched and unique keywords array then it groups of similar words

Comment: this will work only with mongodb 3.4 or greater than 3.4

Comment: thank you so much @shubham for your answer. it is what exactly what I wished though it would take some time to understand this.